# Referenced file contains errors

Tags: java, xml, spring, eclipse, xsd

I'm having a problem when I try to validate the application context for my java web application with `spring` and `zk spring`.

my `applicationcontext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:zksp="http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core"

        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core/zkspring-core.xsd ">
```

I receive the following error:

```
Referenced file contains errors (http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core/zkspring-core.xsd)
```

The error detail stated that I should have a white space between `systemid` and `publicid`. I've added the white space, but the error remains.

> work with 
>   Eclipse Kepler
>   JDK 1.7
>   zkoss framework
>   spring

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issues with the schemas themselves (successfully validated in oXygen after closing the `beans` tag). It may have to do with the other tools.

Comment: What software provided the (partial?) error message?  Always paste the ***exact*** error message into your question.  Never paraphrase.  Regardless, `http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core/zkspring-core.xsd` has no errors; perhaps knowing so will help you identify the disconnect.  Voting to close as lacking a [mcve]...